# vhdl equivalent for initial block in verilog

Tags: vhdl, verilog

I am trying to convert some Verilog code to VHDL. I have difficulties to translate initial block in Verilog to VHDL properly.

As far as I know, the initial block corresponds to the process statement without a sensitivity list but we have to add a "wait" statement before the "end process".I tried it but it did not work. I tried some other methods too (using exit clause, conditional clause ( wait until), "for- generate"  without process, etc) but none was successful.

Here is the Verilog code I want to convert, and it works properly

```
module MyRAM  #(parameter DATA_WIDTH=24, parameter ADDR_WIDTH=10)
(
input [(DATA_WIDTH-1):0] data,
input [(ADDR_WIDTH-1):0] read_addr, write_addr,
input we, clk,
output reg [(DATA_WIDTH-1):0] q
);

// Declare the RAM variable
reg [DATA_WIDTH-1:0] ram[2**ADDR_WIDTH-1:0];

initial 
begin : INIT
    integer i;


    for(i = 1; i < ((2**ADDR_WIDTH)-1); i = i+1) begin
        if (i == 132)   ram[i]   = 24'h550000;
        else if (i == 133)  ram[i]   = 24'h005500;
        else if (i == 134)  ram[i]   = 24'h000055;
        else    ram[i]   = 24'h000000;
    end
    //*/
end 

always @ (negedge clk)
begin
    // Write
    if (we)
        ram[write_addr] <= data;
        q <= ram[read_addr];
end

endmodule
```

and this is the VHDL code I have written so far:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity MyRAM is 
generic
(DATA_WIDTH: integer;
ADDR_WIDTH: integer);

port
(
data :in std_logic_vector ((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
read_addr :in std_logic_vector((ADDR_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
write_addr :in std_logic_vector(( DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
we :in std_logic;
clk :in std_logic;
q :out std_logic_vector( 23 downto 0)
);
end MyRAM;

    architecture behavioral of MyRAM is

  constant case1:std_logic_vector(23 downto 0):= 
 (16=>'1',18=>'1',20=>'1',22=>'1',others=>'0');
 constant case2:std_logic_vector(23 downto 0):= 
 (8=>'1',10=>'1',12=>'1',14=>'1',others=>'0');
 constant case3:std_logic_vector(23 downto 0):= 
 (0=>'1',2=>'1',4=>'1',6=>'1',others=>'0');

   type ram is array ( 0 to (2**ADDR_WIDTH-1)) of 
   std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0); 


    shared variable origram:ram;
    signal s_q: std_logic_vector(23 downto 0);

   begin

    process
    begin 

    for ii in 1 to (2**ADDR_WIDTH-1)  loop  
    if (ii = 132) then
                 origram(ii)  := case1;

        elsif (ii = 133) then
                 origram(ii)  := case2;

        elsif (ii = 134) then   
             origram(ii)  := case3;
    else  
                origram(ii)  :=(others=>'0');           
        end if;
  end loop;
  wait;

 end process;   


 process (clk)

 begin   
    if falling_edge(clk) then


      if (we ='1') then 
         origram(to_integer(unsigned(write_addr))) := data;
         s_q <= origram(to_integer(unsigned(read_addr)));
      end if;
      end if;
  end process;     

  q<=s_q;
end behavioral;
```

And this is the error message:
Error (10533): VHDL Wait Statement error at MyRAM.vhd(88): Wait Statement must contain condition clause with UNTIL keyword

I do not have much experience in these languages, so I would appreciate  any kind of help

Comment: I'm using Vivado simulator and your code is working well on this simulator. (Note that your array start from 0 and your init start from 1, the first slot of your array will not be initialized). It's not really an anwser to your question but you can insert a "wait for 1 ps" in your loop to initialize your ram at simulation start.

Comment: The usual method is to use an initialisation function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is both yes and no. While yes, you can do pretty much what you can do in an initial block in a process, in your situation the answer is you are actually initialising a signal. For this you need to use a function, and set the initial value:

```
type ram is array ( 0 to (2**ADDR_WIDTH-1)) of std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0); 

function init_ram return ram is
  variable r : ram;
begin
  -- set the contents of the ram
end function init_ram;

shared variable origram:ram := init_ram;
```

Processes with wait at the end are only for simulation (which would mimic an initial block in verilog used for testbench stimulus)

Note: from VHDL 2002, using a shared variable like this is illegal as it should be a protected type (which is not synthesisable currently). The only reason you might want a shared variable (rather than a signal) to infer a ram is to get write-before-read behaviour in a RAM. It is very annoying most of the Xilinx Inference examples use a shared variable. Switching your code to VHDL2008 will throw the error mentioned above.

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.6.1 Protected type definitions "A protected type implements instantiatiable regions of sequential statements, each of which are guaranteed exclusive access to shared data."  5.6.2 Protected type declarations "Each subprogram specified within a given protected type declaration defines an abstract operation, called a *method*, that operates atomically and exclusively on a single object of the protected type." Not likely to ever be synthesis eligible. Exclusive concurrent access to expressions (impure function calls) isn't possible. Abstracts defining HW is a HLS concept.

Comment: Write before read can also be modeled in a process providing read and write access to objects of class variable declared in the process.

Answer (score 1):

A process with a `ram` variable instead of a shared variable can provide an initial value as well:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity MyRAM is 
    generic (
        DATA_WIDTH: integer;
        ADDR_WIDTH: integer
    );
    port (
        data:       in  std_logic_vector (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        read_addr:  in  std_logic_vector (ADDR_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        write_addr: in  std_logic_vector (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        we:         in  std_logic;
        clk:        in  std_logic;
        q:          out std_logic_vector (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0)
    );
end entity MyRAM;

architecture behavioral of MyRAM is
    constant case1: std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := 
        (16 => '1', 18 => '1', 20 => '1', 22 => '1', others => '0');
    constant case2: std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := 
        ( 8 => '1', 10 => '1', 12 => '1', 14 => '1', others => '0');
    constant case3: std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := 
        ( 0 => '1',  2 => '1',  4 => '1',  6 => '1', others => '0');
    type ram is array ( 0 to 2 ** ADDR_WIDTH - 1) of 
        std_logic_vector(DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0); 
begin

MY_RAM:
    process (clk)
        function init_origram return ram is
            variable ramval:    ram;
        begin
                for ii in ram'left to ram'right  loop
                if ii = 132 then  -- note the presumption ram has at least 135 elements
                    ramval(ii)  := case1;
                elsif ii = 133 then
                    ramval(ii)  := case2;
                elsif ii = 134 then
                    ramval(ii)  := case3;
                else
                    ramval(ii)  := (others => '0');
                end if;
            end loop;
            return ramval;
        end function;
        variable origram: ram := init_origram;
    begin
        if falling_edge(clk) then
            if we = '1' then  -- write before read
                origram(to_integer(unsigned(write_addr))) := data;
            end if;
            q <= origram(to_integer(unsigned(read_addr)));
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture behavioral;
```

This would be useful in IEEE Std 1076-2000, -2002 and -2008 compliant tool chains where shared variables are required to be protected types as well as earlier standard revisions.

IEEE Std 1076-2008
9.3.3 Aggregates
9.3.3.1 General:

> element_association ::=
>        [ choices => ] expression
>   choices ::= choice { | choice }

You can also use the separator '|` to provide multiple values for choices:

```vhdl
    constant case1: std_logic_vector(23 downto 0) := 
        -- (16 => '1', 18 => '1', 20 => '1', 22 => '1', others => '0');
        (16 | 18 | 20 | 22 => '1', others => '0');
```

or even provide a base specifier X bit string for a hexidecimal value here (15.8 Bit string literals).